# Issues calling sub from webmethod

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webmethod

I have a `<WebMethod>` PassPLU that is being called by an angularjs `$http.post`. That `<WebMethod>` then calls another `Sub` LoadData. At the end of this `Sub`, it populates a `asp:HiddenField`. Unfortunately, this causes a `nullreferenceexception`. However, the LoadData `Sub` is also being called directly by an `asp:Button` which works fine.

Here is the `<WebMethod>` and `Sub`:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Sub PassPLU(ByVal pluno As String, ByVal deptname As String)
    Dim currentPage As New plu
    currentPage.LoadData(pluno, deptname)
End Sub

Protected Sub LoadData(ByVal pluno As String, Optional ByVal deptname As String = Nothing)
    Dim productData As New Product
    Dim sqlStr As String

    connection.Open()
    If deptname = Nothing Then
        sqlStr = String.Format("SELECT * FROM PWMv_PLUM_PLUMaster AS a, PWMv_PLUM_Departments AS b WHERE a.pluno = {0} AND a.deptno = b.deptno;", pluno)
    Else
        sqlStr = String.Format("SELECT * FROM PWMv_PLUM_PLUMaster AS a, PWMv_PLUM_Departments AS b WHERE a.pluno = {0} AND b.deptname = '{1}';", pluno, deptname)
    End If
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlStr, connection)
    Dim pluData As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While pluData.Read()
        productData.PLU = pluData("pluno")
        productData.Dept = pluData("deptname")
        productData.DeptNo = pluData("deptno")
        productData.Desc1 = pluData("desc1")
        If Not IsDBNull(pluData("desc2")) Then
            productData.Desc2 = pluData("desc2")
        End If
        productData.UPC = pluData("upc")
    End While
    pluData.Close()

    sqlStr = String.Format("SELECT ingrtext FROM PWMv_PLUM_IngrMaster WHERE ingrno = {0} AND deptno = {1};", pluno, productData.DeptNo)
    command.CommandText = sqlStr
    productData.Ingredients = command.ExecuteScalar()

    sqlStr = String.Format("SELECT * FROM PWMv_PLUM_NutriMaster WHERE nutrino = {0} AND deptno = {1};", pluno, productData.DeptNo)
    command.CommandText = sqlStr
    pluData = command.ExecuteReader()
    While pluData.Read()
        productData.ServSize = pluData("serveuomdesc")
        If Not IsDBNull(pluData("servpercon")) Then
            productData.ServPer = pluData("servpercon")
        End If
        productData.Calories = pluData("calories") / 10
        productData.CaloriesFat = pluData("calfrmfat") / 10
        productData.TotalFat = pluData("totalfat") / 10
        productData.PerFat = pluData("totalfatper") / 10
        productData.SatFat = pluData("saturfat") / 10
        productData.PerSatFat = pluData("saturfatper") / 10
        productData.TransFat = pluData("transfat") / 10
        productData.Cholesterol = pluData("cholesterol") / 10
        productData.PerCholesterol = pluData("cholesterolper") / 10
        productData.Sodium = pluData("sodium") / 10
        productData.PerSodium = pluData("sodiumper") / 10
        productData.Carbs = pluData("totalcarb") / 10
        productData.PerCarbs = pluData("totalcarbper") / 10
        productData.Fiber = pluData("dietfiber") / 10
        productData.PerFiber = pluData("dietfiberper") / 10
        productData.Sugars = pluData("sugars") / 10
        productData.Protein = pluData("protein") / 10
        productData.VitA = pluData("vitamina") / 10
        productData.VitC = pluData("vitaminc") / 10
        productData.Calc = pluData("calcium") / 10
        productData.Iron = pluData("iron") / 10
        productData.VitD = pluData("vitamind") / 10
        productData.VitE = pluData("vitamine") / 10
        productData.Thia = pluData("thiamine") / 10
        productData.Ribo = pluData("riboflavin") / 10
        productData.Niac = pluData("niacin") / 10
        productData.VitB6 = pluData("vitaminb6") / 10
        productData.Folate = pluData("folate") / 10
        productData.VitB12 = pluData("vitaminb12") / 10
        productData.Biotin = pluData("biotin") / 10
        productData.Phos = pluData("phosphorus") / 10
        productData.Zinc = pluData("zinc") / 10
        productData.Mag = pluData("magnesium") / 10
        productData.Iodine = pluData("iodine") / 10
        productData.Copper = pluData("copper") / 10
        productData.Acid = pluData("pantothenicacid") / 10
    End While
    pluData.Close()
    connection.Close()

    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer(New SimpleTypeResolver())
    nutritionData.Value = serializer.Serialize(productData)

    Dim builder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    builder.Append("window.onload = function () {")
    builder.AppendLine("angular.element(document.getElementById('pluPicker')).scope().loadData();")
    builder.AppendLine("}")
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "loadData", builder.ToString(), True)
End Sub
```

Can someone explain why I am getting this exception? I do not understand why it works one way and not the other.

**Update:** Exception Data

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
>   at plu.LoadData(String pluno, String deptname) in \pignet2012\e\pignetprograms\production\plum2\plu.aspx.vb:line 305
>      at plu.PassPLU(String pluno, String deptname) in \pignet2012\e\pignetprograms\production\plum2\plu.aspx.vb:line 225

Comment: My bet would be that the shared webmethod has no capability to access the instance of ScriptManager. Can you post the exact exception with stack trace? It'd be much more informative.

Comment: As a secondary thought, the `LoadData` method should be doing just that and only that. The portion where it is serialized into the startup script should be handled by some other method. With this tight coupling, it reduces its reusability.

Comment: I posted the stack trace. And you're right about the tight coupling. I'll do something about that later.

Comment: Looking at the exception I'm inclined to say that currentPage is null for whatever reason. Given the simplicity of the statements it would seem unlikely, but not knowing what a 'plu' is or how it is constructed I can't speculate.